# How to take the sandpaper off of a Makita palm sander

Tags: powertools, sanding, sander

I need to know how to take the old sandpaper off a palm sander (Makita model B04553).
It is not mine so I am unsure, but there are four latches that I have lifted, thinking that it will loosen and slide out.

How do I get this paper off?

Comment: Can you provide a photo or link possibly a model number?

Answer (score 7):

1. Release the paper-clamp latches.  There will be one or two latches on both sides of the sander.  For that model, they probably look like this (note the 2 red arrows, showing the release motion):

   [image: Makita finishing sander, paper clamp latches]
2. Pull the folded-over edges, of the sandpaper, out from under the clamps.
3. That model may use velcro paper, so expect that you might have to peel the sandpaper off of the base plate.
4. Replace with the same style and size (length/width) of paper.  Assemble in reverse order.  Pre-creasing the folded edges works best for getting the edge under the clamps.

You can find manuals at http://www.makita.com/en-us/Modules/Service/ServiceCenters.aspx.
Here is [a manual for a similar palm sander (pdf)](http://www.makita.com/en-us/Assets/Output/DownloadFile.aspx?FileName=Products/BO4556/owners_manuals/BO4556_OM.pdf) (AKA "Finishing Sander").

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought it should do.. But when the latches the clamp doesn't lift. Must be a bit broken. Thank you anyway, I'll keep trying :)

Comment: The clamps don't come up to far.  Take the sander to a paint or tool store (not most big-box stores).  Someone there can show you hands-on how to do it.